# Is there a limit for Facebook FBML Tabs?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I just created and application for Facebook and added with the help of the FBML 10 tabs, but it doesn't seems to let me add another tab. Is there a limit (10 tabs) or it's just a weird coincidence. Thanks!!

Comment: I have the same issue.Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does have a limit on the number of tabs that can be displayed on a fan page at a single time - excess tabs that are beyond the width limitation are taken to another area that is marked ">>" and on the right side of the tab space.

To rearrange the tabs being displayed by default:

1.) Click the tab you want to move from your fan page
2.) Once the tab is selected, drag it to the left and place it in the order you need to (they're basically drag and drop by pulling the top of the tab left or right).

Hope that helps!